# Forcing the use of a factory object to instantiate a class

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I have the special case where an object needs to be a singleton on a per thread basis. So I'd like to use a static factory method of a `Factory` class to instantiate those instances. To ensure that the factory class is used (since it caches per thread) the constructor needs to be protected.

So let's say I have a class like this.

```
public class XXXX : Model {
    protected XXXX() {
    }
}
```

I would like to use a factory class like this.

```
public class Factory {

     private static Dictionary<int,Model> _singletons;

     public static T Instance() where T : Model {
          int thread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
          if(!_singletons.ContainsKey(thread))
          {
              _singletons[thread] = new T();
          }
          return (T)_singletons[thread];
     }
}
```

Then later I can get a reference to each singleton like this, and the reference will be unique for each thread.

```
XXXX m = Factory.Instance<XXXX>();
```

How can I do this so that the `Factory` class has access to create instances. One issue is that classes will be defined in other DLLs that will be loaded at run-time. All I can know is that they are derived from `Model` and have `protected/private` constructors.

Comment: Is this to prevent mistakes, or as an actual security mechanism? If the latter, there isn't really that much you can do. If the former, there are a lot more options.

Comment: There are hundreds of objects that need to use `Model` objects, but they only need one instance of each type. It's also a multithreaded project so each thread needs it's own singleton. It's not for security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options:

- reflection
- register delegate that creates the class with factory class
- configure your DI container to behave the way you need for that type of classes

Approximate code for delegate approach:

```
public class Factory {
   private static Dictionary<Type, Func<Model>> creators;
   public void AddCreator<T>(Func<T> creator) where T:Model
   {
      creators.Add(typeof(T), ()=> creator());
   }

   public static T Instance() where T : Model 
   {
       return (T)(creators[typeof(T)] ());
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to call `AddCreator` when the classes are loaded. Maybe as part of a static initialization?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - Static constructor of a class you want to use via the factory will not help as it will not be called before first instantiation of the class. You need to figure out your registration mechanism - i.e. some method you call from DLL when it loaded.  You can also use `internal` on constructors so some assembly wide method can register all necessary classes with the factory. If you want auto-discovery of some sort reflection could be better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your `XXXX` classes either need a public constructor, or they need an internal constructor and you define the assembly that contains your factory as a friend assembly inside the assemblies that contain the `XXXX` classes.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach. Never heard of `friend` before. Can this be defined in the base `Model` class and propagate to derived classes?

Comment: No, this is on an assembly level, not on a class level.

Comment: A friend assembly is a VB term.  In C# it's called Internal.

Comment: @Geek No, you are mistaken: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: You are correct.  The term used to identify is internal(svisibleto) in C#, Friend in VB.  If you look at the 2012 (2005 is a bit old :)  ) guide it explains it a bit better.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking to implement is: this Class and ANY of its derivatives MUST use the class factory method, no matter who implements the derived classes (lib consumer, in an other assembly, etc).

In the base class, declare a private no arg constructur and a constructor with a private "key" arg. then declare a templated method that takes a type as argument and uses reflection to instanciate the class.

Why the magic key? because you need at least one public or protected constructor to be able to specialize the base class and as soon as you do that, your letting child classes choose to enforce or not factory use.

A down side is the use of Invoke. slows things down a bit. In the eventually where this is an issue you can always invoke the compile at runtime to spew out the proper delegate for a given type and store those. so you slowly build a dictionary of constructor delegates for each type. but's beyond the scope of this question.

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    private static string factoryKey = "sdfdsfdsfdsfhdfdsgdfsgd";
    private BaseClass()
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("error");
    }

    protected BaseClass( string key)
    {
        if( key != factoryKey)
            throw new ArgumentException("error");
    }

    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : BaseClass
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
        var instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { factoryKey }) as T;

        return instance;
    }

}
```